# jax-rs client api with jersey as implementation and hk2 produces memory leak

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, jax-rs, jersey-client, hk2

I am having a simple serlvet aplication with a Spring 2.5 context.

Because of jax-rs client recommendation (https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/) I am having my client object as a Spring singleton bean and then create WebResource objects that should be easily flushed by the gc.

Closing is done using Spring's Disposable Bean mechanism (debugged, the method get's called).

After a couple of days, my application runs out of memory. Using memory analysers, I can see that I have 500k instances from org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor, which in time leads to a PermGem.

Did you also encounter this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A memory leak in hk2 was fixed in version 2.3.0-b01 which Jersey will soon integrate with.  This one sounds a lot like that one.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the commit message in the hk2, but i forgt to check the version used directly by jersey. I updated the jersey version and still did not understand why the memory leak still occurs, because the problem seemed to have been fixed in May.

Thank you for you answer :)

Comment: There was a memory leak found and fixed in May, but there was another one that was fixed in 2.3.0-b01